# autoprefixer is not defined

Tags: webpack, sass

In my webpack.config.dev.js file within the config folder, I tried adding a loader, so my .scss files can process:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
            options: {
              // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'NOT IE < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                  ],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          require.resolve('css-loader'),
          require.resolve('sass-loader')
        ]
      },
```

However, I get the following error...

Failed to compile.

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
ReferenceError: autoprefixer is not defined

Can anyone help?

Comment: `autoprefixer` has no definition, you have to import it.

Comment: Of course! I added const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'); to my webpack.config.dev.js ... thanks ))